# why android need to use meta-data?

Tags: android, metadata

i found some AndroidManifest.xml have some .

like this:

```
<meta-data android:name="zoo" android:value="@string/kangaroo" />
```

code in Android:

```
ApplicationInfo ai = getPackageManager().getApplicationInfo(activity.getPackageName(), PackageManager.GET_META_DATA);
String zoo = ai.metaData.getString("zoo");
```

i can define a string value in string.xml ,and get it in code very easy.

what's the different between  and string.xml?

Answer (score 3):

This is a bad example.  It looks like the value is data ***used*** by the app.  The manifest is the correct place to store meta-data ***about*** the app.  Placing string data here which is used by the app (i.e. consumed) is also not localisable.

In one of my apps, I have static content in a library.  That library has it's own version number and is shown to the user in the "about" activity.  I could store this as a string constant within the code but it is more logical, and maintainable, to use  manifest meta-data where all of the app version information is stored alongside the SDK versions etc.

To summarise, in the example you have given, the @string/kangaroo value should be in strings.xml.

Comment: So what would you advise for the static const and non-translatable contents? For example an API key from 3rd party SDK, `values.xml` or `meta-data`?